# Menustration / Karet

Tags: halacha, minhag, niddah

Ive been reading the parshiot of Nidda in the Chumash(Leviticus 15:19-30 18:19 20:18), and it seems that the punishment of Karet (20:18) is during menustration. I know that the sages hold that until she immerses shes niddah, but that seems to me to just be the lav from 18:19?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Being with a woman before she immerses but after shes menustrating doesnt seem as though its karet, and maybe not even the lav?